# warning: missing terminating " character

Tags: c++, c-strings, string-literals

I'm making a C++ program that connects to an SQL database. This query is really long and probably not the best way to go about it, but that's besides the point. This error is referring to the first `"` in this code, right before `SELECT`. Not sure what the problem is considering the ending `"` is at the end of the function. I'm assuming that I need to use some escape characters somewhere but nowhere that I put them seem to do anything.

```
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT customers.customerNumber, customers.customerName, customers.phone, customers.creditLimit, orders.orderNumber, orders.orderDate, orders.status, products.productName, orderdetails.quantityOrdered, orde
rdetails.priceEach, employees.firstName, employees.lastName, employees.email
AS returnedInfo
FROM customers
JOIN orders ON customers.customerNumber=orders.customerNumber
JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber
JOIN products ON orderdetails.productCode = products.productCode
JOIN employees ON customers.salesRepEmployeeNumber = employees.employeeNumber
WHERE customers.customerNumber = \'103\';");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal strings needs to end before the line ends. You can work around that by using the preprocessor line-continuation, as in

```
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT customers.customerNumber, customers.customerName, customers.phone, customers.creditLimit, orders.orderNumber, orders.orderDate, orders.status, products.productName, \orderdetails.quantityOrdered, orderdetails.priceEach, employees.firstName, employees.lastName, employees.email \
AS returnedInfo \
FROM customers \
JOIN orders ON customers.customerNumber=orders.customerNumber \
JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber \
JOIN products ON orderdetails.productCode = products.productCode \
JOIN employees ON customers.salesRepEmployeeNumber = employees.employeeNumber \
WHERE customers.customerNumber = '103';");
```

Of use the compilers string-literal concatenation where it concatenates adjacend string literals:

```
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT customers.customerNumber, customers.customerName, customers.phone, customers.creditLimit, orders.orderNumber, orders.orderDate, orders.status, products.productName, orderdetails.quantityOrdered, orderdetails.priceEach, employees.firstName, employees.lastName, employees.email "
"AS returnedInfo "
"FROM customers "
"JOIN orders ON customers.customerNumber=orders.customerNumber "
"JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber "
"JOIN products ON orderdetails.productCode = products.productCode "
"JOIN employees ON customers.salesRepEmployeeNumber = employees.employeeNumber "
"WHERE customers.customerNumber = '103';");
```

Note that both of these will create what is in reality a *single* line. If you want to pass it to the function as multiple lines you need to add the newline `\n` at the end of each "line" yourself. Or use raw string literals as mentioned in [the answer by druckermanly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58683268/440558).

On a side-note: As you might have noticed, I don't escape the single quoted "string". In double-quoted strings you don't have to escape the single-quote.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the error but now I've got the problem where only the last selection (in this case employees.email) is being shown when I print to the screen. I'm thinking maybe I have to parse through the function that returns it or something. Or maybe I need to rethink my entire approach lol

Edit: Yep, the function that grabs the string to print it to the screen must store each data entry in a linked list. Should have it working now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You want a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (introduced in C++11). The problem is that, by default, you can't put an actual newline (instead of `\n`) in your string, but you can with raw string literals.

If you're not using C++11 or later, you can use other techniques (line continuations, or concatenated sequential strings) but this is often the cleanest way to represent your intent if it's available to you.

Here's an example using your query:

```
res = stmt->executeQuery(R"SQL(
  SELECT 
    customers.customerNumber,
    customers.customerName,
    customers.phone,
    customers.creditLimit,
    orders.orderNumber,
    orders.orderDate,
    orders.status,
    products.productName,
    orderdetails.quantityOrdered,
    orderdetails.priceEach,
    employees.firstName,
    employees.lastName,
    employees.email
  AS returnedInfo
  FROM customers
    JOIN orders ON customers.customerNumber=orders.customerNumber
    JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber
    JOIN products ON orderdetails.productCode = products.productCode
    JOIN employees ON customers.salesRepEmployeeNumber = employees.employeeNumber
  WHERE customers.customerNumber = '103';
)SQL");
```

Comment: Getting the same error with this solution, so I'm assuming my C++ version is outdated. I'm using emacs from a terminal connected to my school's server if that explains anything. Still good information to know, thank you.

Comment: Post what version of the compiler you're using and what command you're using to compile the code with in your question, it can help in the future. With `g++` you might only need to add `--std=c++11` to your compilation command. But if this is for school, they might not give you the flexibility when it comes to grading, so it might not be worth the risk there. :(

Comment: I'm using emacs 24.3 using `g++ -Wall -o mysql_test -I/usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8/jdbc mysql_test.cpp -L/usr/lib64 -lmysqlcppconn `

Comment: Note that you cannot use raw string literals that include newline characters with the preprocessor, as in `#define` contents.